# C# Autoscrollの初期位置について

Tags: c#

現在C#を使ってwindowsアプリケーションを作成しているのですが、フォームにautoscroll=trueを設定した場合、フォームロード時に下までスクロールされた状態で表示されます。この動作は仕様でしょうか？またスクロールをさせたくないので、解決策などを教えて頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

フォームの表示時にフォーカスが当たっているコントロールが表示範囲外にある場合、その要素が表示されるようにスクロールします。基本的にはこれは自然な動作ですので、変更すべきではありません。まずは初期フォーカスが適切かどうかを確認してください。

どうしてもスクロールを行いたい場合は、`Form.Load`より後（例えば`Form.Shown`イベント）で`VerticalScroll.Value`や`HorizontalScroll.Value`に0を設定すれば強制的にスクロール位置を変更できます。

Comment: フォーカスが当たっているコントロールが表示されるようにスクロールされるんですね。勉強になりました。フォームロード時に、フォーカスを指定することで問題を解消することが出来ました。ありがとうございました。